# How can I protect my site from the multiple post requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Any user can 'like' photos on my site. But if he presses the button many times (10 for example), the 10 post requests will be sent to the server.
I tried to solve with the help of sessions.
I thought this code would take likes only each 5 seconds. But it doesnt! There are my action and before_filter:

```
def like
   photo.create_like if session[:voted].nil?
   session[:voted] = Time.now.to_a.first(3).reverse.join
   redirect_to root_path
end


def check_session
  a = Time.now.to_a.first(3).reverse.join
  b = a.to_i - session[:voted].to_i  
   session[:voted] = nil if b >= 5

end
```

Comment: How about your disable the submit button using JavaScript?

Comment: You could create a database-level "unique constraint" on `likes`, forcing only one pair of photo-user to exist. Restricting the interface is unreliable, request forgery is still possible. Restrict the underlying model instead. I'm not publishing this as an answer as I'm not fully aware if that would suit your logic, i. e. if you don't have a `User` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with sessions (at least not with the default session store): by default rails stores the session in a cookie.

Cookies are sent by the browser as part of the request, and the response from your server can optionally update them. If you click on your like button several times in quick succession then you'll fire off several requests, each containing cookie data representing the current state of the session. Your response updates the session, but it's too late for the requests that have already been sent - their session data has been already been sent to the server and won't include any changes made by the responses.

As others have said, a bandaid is to use Javascript to restrict multiple submission but the only robust way to deal with this is at the database level ( with a unique index on the likes table).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `reverse` in your `like` method, so the comparison doesn't work. It should be:

```
session[:voted] = Time.now.to_a.first(3).reverse.join
```

Also in `like` you're using `session[:voted]` and in `check_session` you're using `session[:time]`.

Although this won't work perfectly either. It would be better to use a Unix timestamp for this and let `check_session` return a boolean. Something like this:

```
def like
  photo.create_like if check_session
  session[:voted] = Time.now.to_i
  redirect_to root_path
end

def check_session
  session[:voted].blank? || (Time.now.to_i - session[:voted]) > 5
end
```

Comment: Thx for your help but I carelessly copied code from my project. This is the reason of the errors that you describe.
But. I did as you said and nothing changed. 10 fast clicks on button gives me 10 likes on photo.

Answer (score 0):

disable the button with 

    `<%= submit_tag "Login", 'data-disable-with' => "Please wait.." %>`

You could add a conditional in your views to show voted or want to vote? if the user voted already